# Does VSCode support Python .pyi files for IntelliSense?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, type-hinting, mypy

In VS Code, I tried importing a module called `foo.py` that has a type hinting [stub file](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#stub-files) `foo.pyi`. I want to get code autocompletion based on the type hints in the `.pyi` file, as [PyCharm does](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-product.html#stub). However, the .pyi file does not seem to have any effect. Does anyone know if this feature is supported?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be supported if you use the [Pylance language server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) which will set `"python.languageServer": "Pylance"` as a side-effect of installing it.

Comment: It would be helpful for newcomer's to add a little more context, how do you add a stub file?

Comment: @user1767754 I don't understand what that has to do with my answer? The question specifically said to assume a stub file exists, so explaining how to create a stub file or where to place it is out of scope for any answers to the question.

Comment: @BrettCannon, i think @user1767754's intention is to know where to put the pyi file, which is very important. 

1) is it anywhere in the computer? 

2) or at the same folder the .py file located, 

3) or in a subfolder named `typings` or `stubs`? or something else

Comment: @aaron the answer is 2: the `.pyi` file goes next to the `.py` file is is providing type hints for.

Comment: Is there also a way to put them somewhere else? Putting them next to the source is impractical when you want to provide stubs for 3rd party packages. Those would likely be managed by a package manager and not checked in, while the stubs _would_ be checked in. Presumably for this reason, MyPy accepts an env var (`MYPYPATH`) indicating where to look.

Comment: @AdamAL see https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release for your setting options (which allows for what you're after)